# black box in middle of illustrator CC art board

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, artboard

I'm new to Illustrator and I'm making an illustration, the problem is when I moved the red rectangle, the surrounding border seems to stay there, I can't select it and it does not move or remove, and when I click on the eye button beside layers, I figure out it doesn't belong to any layer. 
I searched about it and I know it's not my art board.
What can it be and how can I remove it?

I hope it's not a redundant post.

[image]

Comment: I think it may be a redundant art board but how can I remove it anyway?

Comment: have you tried the artboard tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the artboard tool (Shift+O) and then click the small "x" in the top right corner of the extra artboard. Alternatively, use the Artboard Panel and select the stray artboard and delte from there.

Comment: thank you very much, it turns out the black box IS an extra art board.